# How to find a row?

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe of 1000s of row and columns..

I need to find a particular row, by means of its rowname (so I know the rowname, but do not know which position it is in).. so for example

```
         V1   V2   V3   V4
sunny    23   78   56   56
vicky    89   89   22   11
nikki    09   76   99   27
suchi    00   88   38   09
kitty    89   02   89   90
```

So in a huge while (like above), lets say, i need to find and extract the row which has the row name "nikki", so my result should be

```
         V1   V2   V3   V4
nikki    09   76   99   27
```

I know it might be simple, but can anyone help me know how to achieve that?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Just use `df["nikki",]`

Comment: @juba could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To subset a data frame by row names, you can just use a character string or vector as row indexing to the `[` operator :

```
df["nikki",]
```

Or :

```
df[c("nikki","sunny"),]
```

Comment: If you actually want to know what row it is, rather than retrieve the row data,  I think `which(rowNames(df)=="nikki")` will get you the row number itself.